# Rambam's Talmud Commentary

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-gemara, rambam, commentaries

Where can I find Rambam's commentary on Bavli (whatever remains of it) besides for his commentary on tractate Rosh HaShana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is printed in the last volume (volume 7) of the [Mekhon HaMaor edition](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/40526/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%96-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) of Peirush HaMishnayot.

Comment: Which tractates are included in that edition, aside for Rosh Hashanah?

Comment: @Chaim many, but it should be clarified that the commentaries on man tractates include only very brief passages. This is because, it is simply a compendium of whichever manuscripts were found. It should additionally be noted that there is evidence that Rambam's Talmud commentary was never finalized for publication. Oh, and there is some question whether he is actually the published commentary is actually Rambam's commentary.

Comment: @mevaqesh in my library i have ramboms hilkoth yarushalmi and some papers on it if you want to check it out. according to mori roson arsui he doesnt believe ho rambom zl wrote it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlQ1VMLVJaQ3FnQ1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob That is not what mori roson arusi said. All he said is that "ולא בכדי לא התייחסתי לחידושי הרמב"ם על
הש"ס, ולספר ההלכות על הירושלמי, **כי הם לא מן היצירות שהרמב"ם דאג לשמרם**" That is, Rambom never published these works; not that he did not write them! If anything, he implies that Rambom did write them!

Comment: @mevaqesh you are right. i mightve misremembered what he said as i read this last year. if you are interested in other papers i have additions to the yarushalmi here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlM1NCU1B4cU8zRlU/view https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlYXJDMjFzLTd6amc/view
and some more papers: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlWE9ISjJTRkZpY2M/view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlejBTM1NYUHZ2UHc/view 
http://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/Taylor-Schechter/fotm/september-2011/index.html 

it is said ho rambom had started writing the peirush on the yarushalmi as the rif had already wrote a peirush on the bavli. but he saw people needed day to day halokhoth as they were uneducated due to the monopoly of learning halokhoth only from rabbonim, therefore he had made the mishnei toro